# Strange audio signal from unknown source

Tags: audio, signal

today I stumbled upon one folder in my backups I totally forgot about.
It contains an audio file, a spectrogram and some observation.
In mid 2017 (starting from june) my speakers began to (seemingly randomly) play 1,4 seconds of the same audio during different times. It was a 1 kHz tone. You can check the full 1,4 seconds of the audio here:

It played at different times and I could not detect any process as the source of the sound. I could capture the sound through my sound card (Asus Xonar D1) though. Does anybody know what this sound means and why it could have been played? My observations:

- That sound was played more often between 00:00 and 02:00
  UTC+2 (Germany)
- 1410 ms duration, 1 kHz frequency
- rise to amplitude in 9ms, comedown as well

I tried to reconstruct the durations of the sound and the silence in ascii:

Legend:

{DURATION} := Duration of the 1 kHz signal

[DURATION] := Duration of the silence

{ 209 ms } [ 58 ms ] { 74 ms } [ 58 ms ] { 74 ms A} [ 58 ms ] { 75 ms B} [ 191 ms ] { 76 ms C} [ 58 ms ] { 75 ms D} [ 191 ms ] { 209 ms }

A - additionally very weak signals appeared on an irregular basis during 7 ms

B - [...] 3 ms

C - [...] 5 ms

D - [...] 10 ms

Figure ( P = Pause (~58ms), E = One Unit of the sound (~75ms) ):

PPP E P E P E P EEE P E P EEE PPP

Message / Body maybe: E P E P E P EEE P E P EEE

Thanks in advance for everybody trying to solve the riddle.

Best regards,

sea212

Comment: sounds like someone transmitting morse code over radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is morse code.

It translates to

BIT

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I wonder how whoever did this got my system to play that sound. Interesting.

Comment: were there any more sounds or was it just BIT over and over?

Comment: It was BIT everytime